# Regex operation cost

Tags: c#, regex, performance

So bottom line, speed REALLY matters to me. Every millisecond, so I want to see which method is the fastest.

I'm my program, I have various cases with different flags (flag[1] - flag[7]). To see how to handle the output, I must match the input with one of various patterns (pattern[1] - pattern[7]). So here is the question, is it better match the string with pattern[1], if it matches, handle it, if not try to match it to pattern[2] (pretty much doing the matching 7 times) OR to put ALL patterns into one regex with a split like:

```
"^[patterns[1]|pattern[2]|...]$
```

see if matches, and if it does, do a split on the string to get the flag value (it is always in the end) and handle it accordingly?

So bottom line: 7 different matches against 1 match and a split.

Note: based on the provided data, I will attempt to sort the 7 matches, so the one that is most likely to occur will be matched first.

I want to keep this question time-oriented, but for suggestions and decision making, the probability of the string being accepted after first match is roughly 91.3%

Comment: a) your pattern is wrong, it should have parentheses instead of square brackets, and if you're concerned with performance it should be `^(?:...|...|...)$` b) why don't you just run both implementations on some large example input and measure the execution time?

Comment: You should set up a simulation for testing this in an environment as close to production as possible. It'll be hard to beat actually running the code. C# has a great `Stopwatch` class in `System.Diagnostics`.

Comment: It would be better to match one by one because if one match is found, it handles it instead of finding a match that we know wont be found.

Comment: I for one, would like to see the results of whatever testing you do.

Comment: @Anon it's not like the engine keeps searching after it has already found a match

Comment: @m.buettner If he is matching all of them at the same time, it will evaluate all. (Depending on how he is matching)

Comment: Hand coding to your specific need will almost surely be faster than a general purpose tool like regex. How much faster, and whether the difference is enough to matter you'll need to find out through benchmarking.

Comment: I have a set of data with 24000 or so entries, so I thought of using that as my test cases. I'm currently writing the Regex for all the patterns (there are various special cases for every flag type) and @m.buettner sorry for the wrong pattern. I just threw something as a visual, but you are right.

Comment: Side question: Is there is a big difference between match.Groups[x] and string.substring() for retrieving a certain portion of the string performance wise?

Comment: @Alexey again: why don't you just test it?

Comment: You've asked a question that's so narrowly focused on your data that there's no hope of us answering it unless you supply us with the exact search strings and some sample data. In general, a regex approach would be faster. But in your specific instance you'll have to create a test harness and, you know, profile it yourself. See http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/.

Comment: To your last question, `match.Groups[x]` should be faster than `substring`, because the string is already created. `substring` would have to create the string ... and then the GC would have to dispose it at some point. That said, the difference might be huge in relative terms (i.e. one is many times faster than the other), but in absolute terms we're talking microseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got 24783 entry file to test the results.

When using 7 different regexes, I ran it through and got 0.1932ish seconds for the first run and 0.14-0.16 for all consecutive runs (Regex compile time).

When using just 1 Regex (mashed all 7 regexes into 1), I got 0.262 for the first compile and 0.18-0.21 for consecutive runs.

Maybe because the regex that I ran first covered most of it (as mentioned before, it used like 91.3% of the cases), the mashed regex did perform quite well.

I did extra operations and found that I still have to split the string afterwards for processing purposes, so it all came down to 7 regexes in if-else statements vs. 1 huge Regex.

End test on 24k sample - roughly 0.05 second difference.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally clear exactly what your search criteria are. You hint that the match string is always at the end. So here are some simple time tests to give a general idea. The tests search for two strings, the first of which is not present in the target, the second of which is present.

```
string.IndexOf 240 nanoseconds (to find string anywere in string, not just at end)
string.EndsWith 210 nanoseconds
Regex.Match 1,285 nanoseconds
precompiled Regex 648 nanoseconds
```

The test code is below. It uses a little [benchmarking utility](http://blog.softwx.net/2013/01/benchmarking-c-code.html) I wrote that removes the timing test overhead (the bracketing loops, etc) from the results. I'm not a regex expert, so hopefully my search pattern is comparable to the string tests.

```
string s = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzsomething";
string search1 = "thinker";
string search2 = "something";
int pos = 0;
new Bench().Time("string.IndexOf", (c) => {
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if ((pos = s.IndexOf(search1)) < 0) {
            pos = s.IndexOf(search2);
        }
    }
});
bool found = false;
new Bench().Time("string.EndsWith", (c) => {
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (!(found = s.EndsWith(search1))) {
            found = s.EndsWith(search2);
        }
    }
});
string pattern = "(" + search1 + "|" + search2 + ")$";
Match match = null;
new Bench().Time("Regex.Match", (c) => { for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) match = Regex.Match(s, pattern); });
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
new Bench().Time("precompiled", (c) => { for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) match = regex.Match(s); });
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see how a pre-compiled Regex performs.  I suspect it will be faster than the 'simple' approaches, depending on the patterns, as the generated state machine can take advantage of pattern commonalities.

Comment: @DanBryant - good idea. I've added that to the post. To be honest, I expected regex to be slower than straight string methods by a larger amount that it actually turned out to be.

Comment: If the input contains the search string, but not at the end, using `IndexOf` will incorrectly report a found match. You probably should use `LastIndexOf`, and then check to see that the result plus the length of the search string is equal to the length of the input. Note also that the regex times will remain fairly constant as the number of search strings increases, but the time required for the iterative approaches will steadily increase.

Comment: @hatchet, As you increase the number of patterns being matched and include patterns with more letters in common, you'll likely see the relative speed increase further.  At some point, Regex should overtake the standard string methods.  Also, 'IsMatch' will be slightly faster than 'Match' if you don't care about which match is found.

Comment: @JimMischel - you're right about IndexOf. I was originally searching for strings anywhere, and then changed to just searching for at the end. I added the EndsWith, but forgot to update the IndexOf.

Comment: @DanBryant - I found the opposite to be true. Doubling the search strings from 2 to 4, where only the last one matches, EndsWith increased to 375 nanoseconds, but precompiled Regex increased to 2,540 nanoseconds. That makes sense for EndsWith, because non-matches should take less time than matches, so adding two non-matches should slightly less than double the time. I don't have an explanation for why Regex quadrupled its run time.